# " " in url links becomes "`" after published to GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-pages

My file name in computer:

```
`2013/08/27/MathJax in MarkDown.html`
```

published to GitHub, then the name was wrong

```
`http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax+in+MarkDown.html`
```

Actually you can see the right page is

```
`http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax%20in%20MarkDown.html`
`http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax in MarkDown.html`
```

`space` becomes `+`

---

I'm on windows 8, with jekyll.

configure.yml

markdown: rdiscount
pygments: true

Comment: There are no spaces in webpage filenames. They are encoded as `%20` so you'll have to remove the spaces or use the YAML slug frontmatter

Comment: @random why jekyll doesn't convert `space` into `%20` but `+`, how to set?